# CoreData - "join" rows from the same entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm quite new to Core Data and want to apologise in advance if i wil use sql terminology only to try to explain my question better. I did search the net but didn't find answer to it in some clean manner. Is it possible with Core Data to 'join' two rows - at search time - from the same entity that have some unique 'external' id (not the one provided by core data at insertion time). For exaple i have one table that has fields:

```
unique_id | description      | iso_code 
----------------------------------------
13        | some desc        | code A 
13        | some other stuff | code B 
13        | some foo         | code C

----------------------------------------
16        | some fun desc    | code A 
16        | some other stuff | code B 
16        | some foo bar     | code C
```

So every row has the same id of 13 or other, I would want to "join" such sets of same id at fetch time and for example sort such joined result sets by description for example - where  iso_code is code C. then display the results in table view.

Is possible to do this without additional multiple array and dictionary manipulations in memory at runtime - eg getting 3 x more results then combining them into reduced filtered collection that will be displayed. Or without using one entity more and create relations with it.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is not a wrapper for SQLite. Core Data is not a relational database. As a net result, Core Data does not do joins.

Core Data is a persistent object graph. You can search the object graph.

What you'd do is run an `NSFetchRequest` with a predicate of `unique_id = 13`, get three separate instances of your entity back and proceed processing from there. You can specify the sort descriptors on the request to achieve sorting.

You can use `NSFetchedResultsController` automatically to wire a particular request to a table, leaving you really only to write the specific view stuff.

EDIT: as to your other concerns, Core Data has quite an advanced memory management system where objects scale up from being plain faults (essentially just a table name + row number if your persistent store is SQLite), still being faults but having their information inside Core Data's cache (SQLite doesn't multithread, Core Data does, so it does some intermediate result caching) or being entirely present in memory (ie, all fields attached directly to the object). Core Data will automatically go to the store as needed to transition through the states*.

(*) though SQLite is very much the weak link in any modern application because of its c.1995 single-threaded nature; when performance tweaking you often want to compel Core Data to do a full fetch rather than fault automatically because otherwise your main thread can end up locked on 'background' activity as someone else has the SQLite lock. Depends on your workload and how you've arranged your threads or queues though, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any unique id in your model as Core Data will [automatically] provide that.  When you link entities together in your model then generate the entity files, you'll find something like this in the header file:

```
@interface User (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addGoalObject:(Goal *)value;
- (void)removeGoalObject:(Goal *)value;
- (void)addGoal:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeGoal:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

In the example above, there is a "user" entity and a "goal" entity.  The model relates these tables but it is not my problem as the programmer to provide any key field on which to join these tables as one would do in SQL.  In fact, Core Data's function is to abstract the model away from the database and your code really has little interest in the format in which data are stored.  So, Core Data will decide how to handle what you're calling "join".

When you need to access a Goal for a given User, you'll do so through these accessor methods, which allow you to get to the various entities linked to a particular user through the method calls above.

This has been a difficult transition for me, but you are better off if you never used SQL just about.  It just does all that stuff for you.  And if you try to use SQL concepts (like providing for unique IDs) you're going to ultimately find it creates so many problems and solves none.